# Flipping a Window in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, nswindow, flip

How can I flip an NSWindow so I can press a button, and the window will "flip" like on Dashboard and the content view of the NSWindow changes.

Comment: See it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24567190/nswindow-flip-animation-easy-and-universal/24567191#24567191

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Step 1: Center the window on a vertically-aligned fulcrum.
Step 2: Push down on one side.

OK, that's not it. ☺

Mike Lee wrote one and put it in the public domain, and [Drew McCormack improved it](http://www.mentalfaculty.com/mentalfaculty/Blog/Entries/2010/9/22_FLIPPIN_OUT_AT_NSVIEW.html). [Rainer Brockerhoff wrote one, too](http://brockerhoff.net/src/), and put his under an MIT license. So you have your choice.

Comment: The first link from Mike Lee is down :-(

Comment: @auco (plus whoever upvoted your comment): After reaching out to Mike via Twitter and getting responses [1](https://twitter.com/bmf/status/211612192842334209), [2](https://twitter.com/drewmccormack/status/211728938878238720), I've updated the link.